# Chrome search results not find specific string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking at a website and I see they validate a UK postcode. An error message appears when I enter an invalid one:

[image]

I see from the network tab of Chrome that no request was made so I presume they are doing this with javascript. So in Chrome I searched all files (using cmd + alt + f buttons on the MAC). The string 'post code' reveals no results. The string 'Incorrect' reveals some results but nothing related to this error message.

Am I missing something? How can this message be displayed yet chrome doesn't find the strings in a search of all the website's frontend files?

Comment: Impossible to know what's happening without anything to look at.

Comment: `onkeyup=someFunction("postcodeformat",this)` and then `message = "incorrect "+fieldnames[passedString]`  - many many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Try setting a *DOM modification breakpoint* on a parent of the node where the error appears.

Comment: @mplungjan shouldn't that appear in the chrome search?

Comment: Maybe not in the way you expect it.

Comment: @wOxxOm good idea, I've narrowed it down to a javascript library now